# Jmeter doesn't resolve parameter (from CSV Data Set Config) into request

Tags: jmeter

Is try to use the CSV Data Set Config to insert a different username password for each Thread.

When posting to a login page the value of the password variable isn't resolved. The username variable is no problem. The variable is correctly loaded into the Thread because the Debug Sampler is showing the correct value for the password. I already tried to change the name of the variable, perhaps it clashes with some other variable name, but that didn't work.

Perhaps it's because the password field is a different type of input field?

Please let me know if need to clarify this more.. :)

Screenshot to clarify the situation:

1 - CSV-File
[image: 1 - CSV-File]

2- CSV Data Set Config
[image: 2- CSV Data Set Config]

3 - Result Debug Sampler
[image: 3 - Result Debug Sampler]

4 - HTTP Request of the login page
[image: 4 - HTTP Request of the login page]

5 - Result of the send request to the login page
Because here the variable isn't translated to the value the login process fails.
[image: 5 - Result of the send request to the login page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *CSV Data Set Config* element, in *Variable Names (comma-delimited)* field you have usernamecsv, pwdcsv... You need to remove space after comma!

> usernamecsv, pwdcsv ---> usernamecsv,pwdcsv

This will solve your problem.